# batch file to automate tree command > pdf file

Tags: batch-file, tree

I am new to batch files but was looking to create one that would use the tree command to write a .txt file of the directory in which the batch file is located and then convert that .txt file to a Word file or PDF that the every day user could view.
This was my attempt at the first part of the process;

```
tree %~dp0  >  %~dp0/"Folder Contents.txt" /A /F
```

but this gave me an "Invalid Path" message in the .txt file
If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `>"%~dp0Folder Contents.txt" tree "%~dp0." /A /F`

Comment: Thanks JosefZ for the help and quick response

Comment: [geisterfurz007's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40735450/3439404) merits reward; please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JosefZ has placed the correct command in the comments but I thought I would add a bit of an explanation here:

Think of how you path would look like with your command. It would be like `C:\PathTo\Batch\/"FolderContent.txt"` which actually is not a valid path.

`%~dp0` will end with a `\` so the `/` in the command from the question is syntactically incorrect.

Further the double quotes should be placed around the total path as JosefZ did in his comment. If you do not do that the path will contain these quotes and will be invalid.

JosefZ further added double quotes and a single `.` around and at the end of `%~dp0` after your tree command. The quotes are there to include possible whitespaces into your folder-path and the `.` to include folders with subfolders as well. You will get an error message if you do not.

Last thing is that he placed the output file at the beginning of the command and got rid of spaces. You can basically place your output file anywhere however. Although you should notice that you should not contain spaces between `>` and your output-file-path.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you taking the time to explain it to me. It's seems to make complete sense. This will really help us in our file explorations.

Comment: @AAlessi If thus answer was helpful for you, please consider marking it as your accepted answer by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it. This not only helps me and the community but also rewards you :)